# Is there a more efficient way to convert this phone number to plain text?

Tags: python

I want to convert a phone number with parentheses and a hyphen between the sixth and seventh digit to 10 numbers with no formatting. This code does the trick, but it's unwieldy and I was wondering whether there's a more efficient method?

Thanks!

```
phone_number = "(251) 342-7344"

phone_number=phone_number.replace("(","")
phone_number=phone_number.replace(")","")
phone_number=phone_number.replace(" ","")
phone_number=phone_number.replace("-","")

print phone_number
```

Comment: So many good answers...what to do...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `str.translate`:

```
>>> from string import punctuation,whitespace
>>> strs = "(251) 342-7344"
>>> strs.translate(None, punctuation+whitespace)
'2513427344'
```

Using `str.isdigit` and `str.join`:

```
>>> "".join([x for x in strs if x.isdigit()])
'2513427344'
```

**Timing comparisons**:

```
>>> strs = "(251) 342-7344"*1000
>>> %timeit strs.translate(None, punctuation+whitespace)
10000 loops, best of 3: 116 us per loop                   #clear winner
>>> %timeit "".join([x for x in strs if x.isdigit()])
100 loops, best of 3: 4.42 ms per loop
>>> %timeit re.sub(r'[^\d]', '', strs)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.19 ms per loop
```

Comment: I'm starting to think you're a wizard.

Comment: is that `%timeit` just shorthand or does that somehow actually work in your shell?

Comment: Nice!  I didn't realize how efficient strs.translate could be.

Comment: @Claudiu I am using [IPython](http://ipython.org/) shell, it comes with such [magic](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/tutorial.html#magic-functions) commands.

Answer (score 6):

I'd go for:

```
import re

phone_number = "(251) 342-7344"
print re.sub(r'[^\d]', '', phone_number)
# 2513427344
```

Comment: You can use `\D` instead of [^\d].  Means the same thing: anything but digits.

Answer (score 1):

A batteries-included functional version.

```
>>> ''.join([x for x in phone_number if x.isdigit()])
'2513427344'
```

"efficient" if you are measuring by lines of code, I guess.  You'll have to be the judge of what kind of efficiency you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could strip anything but numbers with a [Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

```
>>> import re
>>> numbers_only = re.compile(r'[^\d]')
>>> numbers_only.sub('', '(251) 342-7344')
```